# Проверить наличие тега в xml, если нет такого, то добавить

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Есть хороший код, но делает немного другое:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
var xml = @"<persons>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк</fio><age>40</age></person>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 2</fio><age>41</age></person>
              <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 3</fio><age>42</age></person>
            </persons>";
var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
foreach (var x in xe.Descendants("fio").ToList())
   x.Remove();
```

Как бы исправить его чтобы при отсутствии тега `<fio>`

```
<persons>
        <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк</fio><age>40</age></person>
        <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd>.....................<age>41</age></person>
        <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 3</fio><age>42</age></person>
</persons>
```

добавлялось `<fio></fio>` в пределах тега `<person>` например так:

```
<persons>
        <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd>ТУТ<fio></fio><age>41</age>ИЛИ_ТУТ <fio></fio></person>
</persons>
```

Comment: Тогда вам нужно пробегать не по fio а по persons. И внутри смотреть если есть fio то норм, иначе удалять.

Comment: Наоборот, если нет fio, то добавлять

Comment: внизу ответ добавил, правда не понял, зачем там Remove()

Comment: А закрывающий тег `</fio>` добавится автоматически или как?

Comment: Да, ты вставляешь его как XElement получается, разметка сама создается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var emptyPersons = xe.Descendants("person")
    .Where(person => person.Element("fio") == null);

foreach (var person in emptyPersons)
    person.Add(new XElement("fio", "Jon Skeet"));
```

Comment: Попробовал этот код. Раньше при отсутствии тега fio в другой программе было исключение, теперь его нет, можно сделать вывод что код работает. Спасибо. Возможно и второй ответ тоже рабочий код, но я не проверил, Тоже спасибо

Comment: Более тщательно проверил выполнение кода, он выполняется, но добавляет в конец только закрывающий тег и с пробелом и слеш с другой стороны - <fio />

Comment: @Андрей -  `<fio />` - это не закрывающий тег. Это тег с пустым содержимым. Значит, в него ничего не было вставлено (в моём примере вставлено имя Джон Скит).

Comment: я оставил вот так без содержимого person.Add(new XElement("fio")); - Это правильно?

Comment: @Андрей - как написано, так и вставляется - пустой тег без содержимого. А правильно это или нет - зависит от задачи.

Comment: А так без содержимого возможно `<fio></fio>` ? или это `<fio />` тоже самое?

Comment: @Андрей - Это нужно задавать отдельным вопросом. Кратко: да - это то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Почему нет?

```
var xml = @"<persons>
                  <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк</fio><age>40</age></person>
                  <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd><fio>Тони Старк 2</fio><age>41</age></person>
                  <person><bd>12.03.1956</bd>Тони Старк 3<age>42</age></person>
                </persons>";
                var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
                foreach (var x in xe.Descendants("person").ToList())
                {
                    if (x.Descendants("fio").Count() == 0)
                    {
                        x.Add(new XElement("fio", "Тонни Старк 3"));
                    }
                    x.Remove();
                }
```

Comment: Тоже рабочий код